# Base64 encoding doesn't fail with invalid characters

Tags: go, encoding, base64

I am trying to ensure a string coming from an http request is valid for use in a base64 url param. I've been experimenting with `base64.RawURLEncoding` as I assumed encoding an invalid string would throw an err, or at least decoding the result of this would fail, however it quite happily encodes/decodes the string regardless of the input.

https://play.golang.org/p/3sHUfl2NSJK

I have created the above playground showing the issue I'm having (albeit an extreme example). Is there another way of ascertaining whether a string consists entirely of valid base64 characters?

Comment: Why do you think that's an invalid string?

Comment: I was under the impression that base64.RawURLEncoding.Encode() would only take strings consisting of base64 chars detailed here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Base64_table

Comment: Those are the characters which are used in the result of a base64'ed string.

Comment: You can *en*code arbitrary bytes in base64 (which is why the encoding functions don't return errors). Only *de*coding can fail.

Comment: Base64 encoding accepts any binary data. This is from the wiki page you posted: "Base64 is a group of similar binary-to-text encoding schemes that represent binary data in an ASCII string format"

Comment: The whole point of Base64 encoding is to take arbitrary bytes and reduce them to printable ASCII characters. There is no such thing as an invalid character for *encoding*, only for *decoding*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify, [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) is an encoding scheme which allows you to take arbitrary binary data and safely encode it into ASCII characters which can later be decoded into the original binary string.

That means that the "Base64-**en**code" operation can take literally any input and produce valid, encoded data. However, the "Base64-**de**code" operation will fail if its input string contains characters outside of set of ASCII characters that the encoding uses (meaning that the given string was *not* produced by a valid Base64-encoder).

To test if a string contains a valid Base64 encoded sequence, you just need to call [`base64.Encoding.DecodeString(...)`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/base64/#Encoding.DecodeString) and test if the error is "nil".

For example ([Go Playground](https://play.golang.com/p/yDabDecynpY)):

```
func IsValidBase64(s string) bool {
  _, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(s)
  return err == nil
}

func main() {
  ss := []string{"ABBA", "T0sh", "Foo=", "Bogus\x01"}

  for _, s := range ss {
    if IsValidBase64(s) {
      fmt.Printf("OK: valid Base64 %q\n", s)
    } else {
      fmt.Printf("ERR: invalid Base64 %q\n", s)
    }
  }
  // OK: valid Base64 "ABBA"
  // OK: valid Base64 "T0sh"
  // OK: valid Base64 "Foo="
  // ERR: invalid Base64 "Bogus\x01"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

base64 encoding works by interpreting an arbitrary bit stream as a string of 6-bit integers, which are then mapped one-by-one to the chosen base64 alphabet.

Your example string starts with these 8-bit bytes:

```
11000010 10111010 11000010 10101010 11100010 10000000
```

Re-arrange them into 6-bit numbers:

```
110000 101011 101011 000010 101010 101110 001010 000000
```

And map them to a base64 alphabet (here URL encoding):

```
  w      r      r      C      q      u      K      A
```

Since every 6-bit number can be mapped to a character in the alphabet (there's exactly 64 of them), there are no invalid inputs to base64. This is precisely what base64 is used for: turn arbitrary input into printable ASCII characters.

*De*coding, on the other hand, can and will fail if the input contains bytes outside of the base64 alphabet — they can't be mapped back to the 6-bit integer.